# Single Sign on configurations and methods available trough Apex?

Tags: apex, api, single-sign-on

Are the Single Sign On setting and methods available trough from Apex controllers?
I would like to create custom VF login page exposing the different authentication options for the user in Customer Community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get the methods from **AuthConfiguration** Class. It contains methods for configuring user settings for users to log into Salesforce using an authentication provider, such as Google or Facebook instead of using Salesforce credentials. You can find the details in this Salesforce [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthConfiguration.htm#apex_Auth_AuthConfiguration_getAuthProviderSsoUrl).

Example:

This example shows how to call some methods on the Auth.AuthConfiguration class. Before you can run this sample, you must provide valid values for the URLs and developer name.

```
String communityUrl = '<Add URL>';
String startUrl = '<Add URL>';
Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = new Auth.AuthConfiguration(communityUrl,startUrl);
List<AuthProvider> authPrvs = authConfig.getAuthProviders();
String bColor = authConfig.getBackgroundColor();
String fText = authConfig.getFooterText();

String sso = Auth.AuthConfiguration.getAuthProviderSsoUrl(communityUrl, startUrl, 'developerName');
```

Refer to this [blog post](http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.in/2014/11/login-with-facebook-for-community-with.html) for implementation.